# Tensorflow minimize integers

Tags: tensorflow, minimize, minimization

I'm trying to implement a function which minimizes over a function where the paramters are given by entries of an array. I tried the sample code:

```
z = tf.Variable(6., trainable=True)

A=np.linspace(-1,1,50)
data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(A, np.float32)

f_x = data_tf[tf.cast(tf.clip_by_value(z,0,25),tf.int32)]

loss = f_x
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1).minimize(f_x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        print(sess.run([z,loss]))
        sess.run(opt)
```

This gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-278fa6e8507a> in <module>()
14 
15 loss = f_x
---> 16 opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1).minimize(f_x)
17 
18 with tf.Session() as sess:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py in 
minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, 
aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
405           “No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for 
ops”
406           “ that do not support gradients, between variables %s and loss 
%s.” %
--> 407           ([str(v) for _, v in grads_and_vars], loss))
408 
409     return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step,

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops 
that 
do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' 
shape=() 
dtype=float32_ref>",
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

As error message states, function you're trying to minimize is non-differentiable. There's simply no way area slicing operation connects to `tf.Variable` you've defined.
This example will work however

```
z = tf.Variable(6., trainable=True)
e = tf.Variable(0., trainable=True)

A = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(A, np.float32)

idx = tf.cast(tf.clip_by_value(z,0,25),tf.int32)
f_x = tf.slice(data_tf, [idx],[1]) 

f_x = tf.reduce_sum(f_x - e)

loss = f_x
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1).minimize(f_x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        sess.run(opt)
        print(sess.run([z,loss]))
```

Edit: You can add a copy of `z` like this

```
zz = tf.identity(z)
```

but it will tie its value to original variable, so you'll still need to add it in final op(in this case `reduce_sum`) to make it differentiable. It' because if you cast it to int and pass as index it stop to be differentiable. In order to make it change you need to have a connection between original value and f_x. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but if I let the code run, the index does not change at all, only e is trained. did I miss something?